# Iterative counting of string matches across columns R

Tags: r, string, text, split, match

I have a data frame with two columns of strings

```
x <- data.frame(a = c("HH UH D", "L EH . M IH N", "EH K . S AE M . P EL"),
                b = c("HH UH F", "L IY . V IH NG", "S AE M . P EL"))
```

I am trying to calculate the number of times the characters in *column b, row 1* match the characters in *column a, row 1*. Then *column b, row 2* to *column a, row 2*, etc. Then adding this count as a new column. So the output of this calculation would be something like:

```
x <- data.frame(a = c("HH UH D", "L EH . M IH N", "EH K . S AE M . P EL"),
                b = c("HH UH F", "L IY . V IH NG", "S AE M . P EL"), 
                c = c(2, 2, 5)) # HH and UH match, so 2 
                                # L and IH match, so 2 
                                # S, AE, M, P, and EL all match, so 5
```

I have tried using something like this:

```
a_characters <- str_split(x$a, " ")
b_characters <- str_split(x$b, " ")
stringcounting <- data.frame()

for (letter in b_characters){
  count <- str_count(a_characters, letter)
  sum_count <- sum(count)
  stringcounting <- rbind(stringcounting, sum_count)
}
```

But the result here is: 
1, 50, 20 rather than 2, 2, 5 (no sense as to why). I imagine something is going wrong in my for-loop and also likely in the way I've split my strings into characters, but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can remove `"."` after splitting the string since we don't want to compare that and calculate matching strings using `%in%` and `sum`.

```
mapply(function(x, y) sum(x[x != "."] %in% y[y!= "."]), 
                      a_characters, b_characters)
#[1] 2 2 5
```

Comment: This is not the same output I get. I get every character with a (1 or 0) based on match, and it returns all 0s for the match of the characters in "S AE M P EL".

Comment: @Ian are you using the same data as shown in your post? It gives me the expected output as shown.

Comment: Ah! Sorry about that. I had accidentally unlisted my str_splits when toying around earlier and didn't change them back. Once removed, I get the same output. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that can do this:

```
    library(stringr)

    matching_words_count <- Vectorize(function(column1,column2){
        return(sum(str_split_1(column1," ") %in% str_split_1(column2," ")))
      })
  
    # use
    df$new_column <- matching_words_count(df$a,df$b)
```